# sklearnでImportError: cannot import name cloneというエラーが出る

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

pythonでランダムフォレストを使おうとしているのですが,以下のエラーが出てきます。
どうすればよいのかご教授お願い致します。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import cpu_count
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .pool import MemmapingPool
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/Users/kudoururiko/Program/random.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import BaseEnsemble
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..base import clone
ImportError: cannot import name clone
```

Comment: ファイル名を変えたら解決しました

Comment: ファイル名はハマりがちですね。

Comment: @blue_bird 参考までにお聞かせ願いたいのですが、`random.py`から何にファイル名を変更したら解決したのでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu skt_test.pyに変更したら解決しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名を`random.py`から他のものに変更してください。
エラーログを詳細に読むと、`random`をimportしようとした所でライブラリの`random`ではなく自分自身をimportしようとしています。

類似の質問: ["Tweepy: ImportError: cannot import name Random"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750961/tweepy-importerror-cannot-import-name-random) (本家StackOverflowより。「sklearn cannot import name」などでググっているとでてきました。)

<sup>(註： この回答はコメント[1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32202/sklearn%E3%81%A7importerror-cannot-import-name-clone%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B?noredirect=1#comment31474_32202)、[2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32202/sklearn%E3%81%A7importerror-cannot-import-name-clone%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B?noredirect=1#comment31521_32202)を参考にした回答です。詳しくはメタポスト[「コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1812/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%8B%E5%BE%8C%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86)をご覧ください）</sup>